# Computational Complexity of HypergeometricPFQ

Tags: special-functions, combinatorics

What is the computational complexity of [HypergeometricPFQ](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/HypergeometricPFQ.html)? I got a result of a product of a multinomial and HypergeometricPFQ and I was wondering if that would be considered a closed form solution depending on the complexity of computing the HyperGeometricPFQ.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: In "traditional" definition of CF, no, but some definitions / authors admit special functions.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 
1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 
2) Read the [faq]!
3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge.
Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)!

Comment: For reference, could you maybe post the hypergeometric result you obtained?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I evaluated the computational complexity in the two main aspects:

1. Time (Runtime/CPU-Time)
2. Space (Memory)

with regard to increasing `i` for artificial parameters:

```
cpl=Module[{a, b, z},
 Table[
  a = Range[i]; b = Range[i]; z = RandomReal[{-10., 10.}];
  AbsoluteTiming[MaxMemoryUsed[HypergeometricPFQ[a, b, z]]],
  {i, 1, 500}
 ]]
```

1. Time complexity: `ListPlot[{cpl[[All, 1]]}]`
   [image: Time complexity]
2. Space complexity: `ListPlot[{cpl[[All, 2]]}]`
   [image: Space complexity]

## Result

By fitting with `Fit` and increasing degrees of monomials I deduced:

1. Time complexity is $O(i^3)$ (polynomial)
2. Space complexity is $O(i)$ (linear)

**System:** *Mathematica* 10.1 on Winx64.

I hope this answers your question.